# How to decrypt encrypted post data of an Android app?

Tags: encryption, http, android

I've seen many Android apps which send encrypted post data, tools like Fiddler and Burp can't decode that data, is there any other tool or method that can decrypt this obfuscated post data?

For example look at this:

```
POST /auth.asmx/create HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: site.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 109

FF 52 FF 67 FF 0A 09 6B FF FF 70 FF 17 FF 5F FF |  R g   k  p   _ 
6C FF FF FF FF FF 2A 2F FF FF FF 6A FF 73 FF 72 | l     */   j s r
FF 42 08 FF FF 77 FF FF 6A FF 22 26 3B 7E 05 FF |  B   w  j "&;~  
FF FF 13 FF FF 57 FF 57 27 5C FF FF 34 2B 1D 49 |      W W'\  4+ I
FF 54 47 73 FF 5F FF 29 FF 1B 6A FF 27 FF 22 FF |  TGs _ )  j ' " 
FF 15 FF 78 FF 0C 7A FF FF FF 41 FF 14 FF 5B 4B |    x  z   A   [K
26 FF 53 10 FF 4D FF 67 FF 61 36 FF FF          | & S  M g a6
```

These are the full headers, I've just taken out the user-agent because it will give away the app as it's a custom.

I've tried decoding the hex but the output is unreadable:

```
ÿRÿgÿ
kÿÿpÿÿ_ÿlÿÿÿÿÿ*/ÿÿÿjÿsÿrÿBÿÿwÿÿjÿ"&;~ÿÿÿÿÿWÿW'\ÿÿ4+IÿTGsÿ_ÿ)ÿjÿ'ÿ"ÿÿÿxÿzÿÿÿAÿÿ[K&ÿSÿMÿgÿa6ÿÿ
```

Can somebody help me with this?

**Note: SSL decryption is enabled and working fine.**

Comment: I'd have a look at the source page that generate this request but, given the number of identical characters in there, it might just be a simple substitution cipher. Have a look at the cleartext you're placing inside the app as well

Comment: There is no encryption standard for POST data. It is not even clear if this is encryption in the first place or if these are just binary application specific data. But it is definitely no `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8` as claimed in the header. What exactly is done here is probably specific to the application. I propose the question as too broad since it is impossible to help based on this. Apart from that it might also be closed because you are trying to break the security of a system which is in most cases considered off-topic here.

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely not urlencoded. If breaking the security of an app is considered off-topic here, where should I ask then?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It is absolutely not off-topic (though it may be too broad). **Help with breaking security is allowed** as long as the asker has demonstrated an understanding of the problem, which he clearly has (i.e. he explained his problem, explained what he tried, and asked for further help). If the OP simply said "here is something encrypted, break it for me" then yes, that would apply.

Comment: @JohnDoe This is the correct place to ask, as long as you demonstrate a basic understanding of the underlying concepts.

Comment: @forest: the OP has not shown that this is encrypted in the first place instead of being just binary application specific data. Instead the OP just posts a blob of data and asks how to decrypt this. All the OP has tried was  hex-decoding it it, i.e. essentially display binary data on the console which of course results in a messed up output - and hex-decoding has obviously also nothing to do with the claimed encryption. In summary: this does not show an understanding of the problem for me and it does not highlight a specific (narrow) problem. Thus I still think that this is off-topic.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich All I'm asking for is a direction. If the problem is too broad, point me in the direction which will help me narrow it down. I'm trying to understand this stuff, I am new to this. IDK why newbies are so hated around here?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Too few is known about the application (i.e. practically nothing) so giving a direction is hard. But you might try to figure out what the payload should contain in terms of information, capture multiple payloads and compare these and then try if you find a common structure in it etc. It is far from trivial and you might find better help in [reverseengineering.se].

Comment: @SteffenUllrich What information is required? I can try to provide.

Comment: @JohnDoe: to cite myself: *"... you might find better help in in [reverseengineering.se]"*. It is not even clear that this has anything to do with security at all - only you are claiming without proof that this is encryption.